# Set the name for each ParallelFor iteration in KFP v2 on Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow-pipelines, kfp

I am currently using `kfp.dsl.ParallelFor` to train 300 models. It looks something like this:

```
...

models_to_train_op = get_models()

with dsl.ParallelFor(models_to_train_op.outputs["data"], parallelism=100) as item:
  prepare_data_op = prepare_data(item)
  train_model_op = train_model(prepare_data_op["train_data"]

...
```

Currently, the iterations in Vertex AI are labeled in a dropdown as something like `for-loop-worker-0`, `for-loop-worker-1`, and so on. For tasks (like `prepare_data_op`, there's a function called `set_display_name`. Is there a similar method that allows you to set the iteration name? It would be helpful to relate them to the training data so that it's easier to look through the dropdown UI that Vertex AI provides.

Answer (score 3):

I reached out to a contact I have at Google. They recommended that you can pass the list that is passed to `ParallelFor` to `set_display_name` for each 'iteration' of the loop. When the pipeline is compiled, it'll know to set the corresponding iteration.

```
# Create component that returns a range list
model_list_op = model_list(n_models)

# Parallelize jobs
ParallelFor(model_list_op.outputs["model_list"], parallelism=100) as x:
  x.set_display_name(str(model_list_op.outputs["model_list"]))
```

Comment: what version of kfp library is this? I get compilation error.

Comment: I also can't get this to work :/ `TypeError: 'LoopArgumentVariable' object is not callable`

Comment: I did not yet :(